# Add prefix for matches in string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have let's say this string:

**"A = Beta * C / Delta + 2";**

Now I want to replace all the variables(A, Beta, C, Delta) with the same name but with a prefix before it, like "x". So it would become:

**"xA = xBeta * xC / xDelta + 2";**

Maybe my head is just tired, but I can't think of a solution for this.

To find matches, it's easy, just test against **/[a-zA-Z]+/** regex, but how in javascript should I get what I found and replace it easily not using multiple function calls?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
var str = "A = Beta * C / Delta + 2";
var prefixed = str.replace(/([a-zA-Z]+)/g, 'x$1');
```

Results in:

```
xA = xBeta * xC / xDelta + 2
```

Comment: jmar777, thanks! Really works. As I believe $1 is the string matched the regex?

Comment: Correct - $1 refers to the first matched "group" surrounded in parenthesis. $2 would be the second group, and so on.